# Docker container with Angular2 app and NodeJs does not respond

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I created new Angular2 app by angular-cli and run it in Docker. But I cannot connect it from localhost.

At first I init app on my local machine:

```
ng new project && cd project &&  "put my Dockerfile there" && docker build -t my-ui .
```

I start it by command:

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 my-ui
```

Then try on my localhost:

```
curl localhost:4200
```

and receive

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Then, I tried switch into running container (*docker exec -ti container-id bash*) and run curl localhost:4200 and it works.

I also tried to run container with --net= host param:

```
docker run --net=host -p 4200:4200 my-ui
```

And it works. What is the problem? I also tried to run container in daemon mode and it did not helped. Thanks.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node

RUN npm install -g angular-cli@v1.0.0-beta.24 && npm cache clean && rm -rf ~/.npm

RUN mkdir -p /opt/client-ui/src
WORKDIR /opt/client-ui  

COPY package.json /opt/client-ui/
COPY angular-cli.json /opt/client-ui/
COPY tslint.json /opt/client-ui/

ADD src/ /opt/client-ui/src

RUN npm install
RUN ng build --prod --aot

EXPOSE 4200

ENV PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"    
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: what OS and version of docker?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you use `ng serve` to run development server and it by default starts on loop interface (available only on localhost). You should provide specific parameter:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

to run it on all interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `angular-cli` to serve the app externally i.e update your npm script to `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`