# Not able to access angular webserver inside linux contianer from windows host

Tags: docker

I am deploying an angular app inside an ubuntu container which is hosted on windows 10. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY app /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl software-properties-common python-pip
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app/ng
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild node-sass
EXPOSE 4200
WORKDIR /
RUN touch start.sh
RUN echo "python /app/server.py &" >> start.sh
RUN echo "cd /app/ng" >> start.sh
RUN echo "ng serve" >> start.sh
RUN chmod +x start.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD ["start.sh"]
```

I run the image using

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 --name=test app
```

Now, the problem is, I am running this container on windows 10 with which I am not very familiar from the docker's perspective of networking. If I would have been running Linux, then I could have easily accessed the app through any browser by visiting `http://localhost:4200` but this is not the case on windows 10 it seems. When I try to access my app through chrome, I get

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I tried to search and found [similar issue](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-navigate-to-container-website-from-host-browser/25035) on docker forums. Taking the suggestions there I tried to access the container through my IPv4 address but failed. I also tried using docker NAT IP `10.0.75.1` but no results. I got hold of the container IP through `docker inspect test` and used the container IP `172.17.0.2` but that too didn't work.

Output of curl from host:

```
E:\app>curl localhost:4200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4200: Connection refused

E:\app>curl 0.0.0.0:4200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 4200: Address not available
```

If I curl inside the container, it works as expected

```
root@97cd2c1e6784:/# curl localhost:4200
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
        <p>Test app</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How to access my angular app from windows host browser? If you want more information please ask for it in comments.

Comment: Could you execute this command and add the results, so we know more about how Docker is running in Windows? `docker-machine ls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching more, I got an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485063/docker-container-with-angular2-app-and-nodejs-does-not-respond?rq=1). I just needed to start the angular server using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` instead of just `ng serve` so that the application runs on all the network interfaces instead of just the loop interface.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED: I just needed to restart the machine :).**
I had a similar issue (but I am not using Docker). When I run the command "**ng serve --host 0.0.0.0**" I can curl it inside the ubuntu **WSL2** instance (screenshot attached) and it works fine!!, but I cannot use the browser (on Windows 10 build 19043) it always returns "**ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**". Any ideas?

[image]

[image]