# Docker with Angular

Tags: angular, docker

I am trying to run a docker container for my Angular program. The docker spins and starts the angular program listening at port 4200. When I look at the docker through the terminal I see all the files. When I try to run `ng serve` on the terminal, I get a error message that the port 4200 is in use. But I am not able to access the program from my browser. When I try `localhost:4200`, I get a connection reset error. Is there a problem with my docker file?

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli 

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I am aware that it's better to put up a dist folder instead of running npm every time. But I am trying to set this up this way for training purposes.

Comment: What does `npm start` actually do?  (It should be in your `package.json` file.)  Plain `ng serve` needs to have a `--host 0.0.0.0` option, see [Docker container with Angular2 app and NodeJs does not respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485063/docker-container-with-angular2-app-and-nodejs-does-not-respond).

Comment: Awesome. I changed the last line to CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"] and I am now able to access localhost:4200 to see my program. Accepted answer